# How to update the first row in the exported query from sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, export, sqlcmd

I am trying to find an easy way of updating the first row in the export of a `sqlcmd` query to `CT_EVENT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`. I found this article in [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425379/how-to-export-data-as-csv-format-from-sql-server-using-sqlcmd) which builds the csv format. I've also checked the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017) for `sqlcmd` parameters.

```
sqlcmd -S DatabaseServer1 -Q "EXEC [db1].[dbo].[MyStoredProc];" -o output.tmp -s "," -W
type output.tmp | findstr /r /v "^-[-,]*-.$"  > "c:\Temp\import_template.csv"
del output.tmp
```

EDIT: I've found the print statement works for this.

```
PRINT 'CT_EVENT,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,';
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: It would be nice if there was a comment as to why you downvoted. I put a lot of time and effort into this question.

Comment: What do you mean by updating the first row? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I would like to replace the entire first row of the file

Comment: Are you trying to create a CSV file, but the "Format grouped..." part introduces problems when importing the CSV into somewhere?

Comment: Yes, I basically just want the exported CSV file to be to spec for import into another system.

Comment: I created documentation for the process, to manually update the first row, but I'd like to sort it out completely on the export.

Comment: I tried using the `h` parameter, but it didn't give me the result I was looking for.

Comment: The issue with the first line had to do with a print line in the stored procedure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about Powershell? It has mighty rich set of features for string manipulation and it's got built-in CSV support too. A quick and dirty way would be like so,

```
# Read the file into a variable, skip 1st row
$data = (Get-Content $myFile | Select-Object -Skip 1)
# Write just the header
set-content -path c:\output.csv -value "my,desired,header,column,,,,,"
# Add actual data
add-content -path c:\output.csv -value $data
```

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to answer. I'll give it a go tomorrow when I'm in the office.